# Gambler's fortune

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, random-walk

Suppose that a gambler with initial capital $a$ is betting against an opponent with infinite capital in a fair game. Given that the gambler is NOT yet ruined until time $n$, what is the expected capital of the gambler at time $n$?

I have an asymptotic argument: the random walk conditioned to to stay positive until time $n$, when scaled in the usual diffusive way, should converge to the Brownian Meander process. What we are looking at is value at time $1$ after scaling. So, the asymptotic limit of expected value of the walk at time $n$, when scaled by $ \sqrt{n} $, should converge to a constant, namely the expected value of the meander at time $1$. This argument should hold for general random variables.

I am wondering if any specific formula is known when it is a simple symmetric random walk. Even a lower bound should be OK for my purpose. Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: By "not ruined until time $n$", do you mean that the gambler **is** ruined at time $n$, or do you mean that at time $n$ the gambler has not yet been ruined?  Also, are these bets of constant size $1$?

Comment: Yes indeed. The gambler will be ruined for sure, but is not yet ruined at time $n$. More mathematically, we have $ \{ S_0 = a > 0, S_1 > 0, S_2 > 0, \dotsc, S_n > 0 \}$ where $ S_i$ is the fortune of the gambler at time $n$.  Also, you are correct - the constant bet size is $1$.

Comment: Your approach would certainly work if ruin mean having exactly $0$ rather than no more than $0$; the conditional expectation would be $\frac{a}{\text{probability not ruined at or before }n}$.  For given $a$ that denominator should be $O(1/\sqrt{n})$

Comment: Henry, How do you get the formula of the conditional expectation?